# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot add property uuid, object is not extensible

Tags: angular-tree-component

I am using `"angular-tree-component": "^8.0.3"` to construct tree for the mine Angular7 Single Page Application(SPA).
I am following the [documentation](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/) and creating tree but getting the following exception onces providing input to nodes in component.

```
core.js:14597 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot add property uuid, object is not extensible
TypeError: Cannot add property uuid, object is not extensible
    at TreeNode.setField (tree-node.model.js:179)
    at TreeNode.set [as id] (tree-node.model.js:170)
    at new TreeNode (tree-node.model.js:30)
    at MapSubscriber.project (tree-node.model.js:444)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber._next (distinctUntilChanged.js:54)
    at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber._next (distinctUntilChanged.js:54)
    at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at SafeSubscriber._error (zone.js:724)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:147)
    at Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:38)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber._next (distinctUntilChanged.js:54)
    at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
```

what might be the cause behind this whether correctly fully data is not replicating to node or some any other type of issue.
Please any one help.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution. Anybody got?

Comment: don't for me trick or what but i did like this  `this.nodes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`
and problem get resolved.